# WGET download happens faster when executed through command line and slowly when executed through Java code

Tags: java, wget

I am downloading a file using WGET through a java code, which takes around 10 mins to download 20 MB file. But on executing the *wget* download through command line, the same file gets downloaded in 7 seconds at 10MbPs speed. Does anyone know why this is? How can I improve my Java code?

Below is the code I have used to download a file using WGET. It takes around 10 minutes to download a 20 MB file. But when I run the wget command through the command line, it happens in seconds!!

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.net.URLConnection;



 public class WGETServer
{



public File download(URL sourceurl, String username, String password, String fileName)
{
    //System.out.println("WGET download() is starting ...");

    File file = null;
    URLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {

        urlConnection = sourceurl.openConnection();

            String userNameAndPassword = username +":"+ password;
            String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode (userNameAndPassword.getBytes());
            //The line which is supposed to add authorization data 
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Internet connection failure or invalid Username/Password.");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        file = new File("file path");
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int character;
        while((character = reader.read()) != -1)
        {
            outputStream.write(character);
        } 
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("downloading completed");
    return file;

}



public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException
{
    URL sourceurl = new URL("https:blablabla");
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String filename = "filename";
    WGETServer WGETdownload = new WGETServer();
    WGETdownload.download(sourceurl, username, password, filename);
}
```

}

Comment: No buffering of the output stream?

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the FileOutputStream with a BufferedOutputStream.

`new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(...))`

Otherwise each and every character written is synchronized to disk by the underlying operating system which is a time consuming process.  This is why buffering is so important.

Comment: but my question is, the file takes 5 mins to download through the code..but when i download the file using wget in command line, the same file is downloaded in 4 seconds!!! why is this??

Comment: Because the way you've written the Java code means that the output is written a single character at a time, rather than in "blocks" of characters for every disk write. Any form of excessive disk IO will kill a programs performance, and you are doing *a lot* of disk IO. I suspect that WGET was written to buffer the output to the files it writes to, which is why its faster. If you don't understand why a write to disk takes a long time, then I suggest you read an operating systems book like "Modern Operating Systems" by Tanenbaum.

Comment: your change did it,...downloading in 5 seconds..thanks a lot :) willr ead up on different types of file readers :)

Comment: @manil it was the writing, not the reading. You buffered the read from the input stream, but not the write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have buffered reader (Good) but then you write the content char by char to the disk (BAD). That kills your performance. It's not the reading, it's the writing.

Comment: ah...i see... is there any alternate method that u would suggest to speed it up??

Comment: Thorbjørn has the solution to your problem :)

Comment: but my question is, the file takes 5 mins to download through the code..but when i download the file using wget in command line, the same file is downloaded in 4 seconds!!! why is this??

Comment: Because.You.Write.Unbuffered. You read a byte from the input buffer and then ask the operating system to append that byte to the file. When it is done, you do the same for the next byte. *write to a buffer*.

Comment: I guess, wget caches the content in buffers too and writes large chunks.

Comment: the change did it,...downloading in 5 seconds..thanks a lot :) will   read up on different types of file readers :)